# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Composer unable to pick composer.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im stuck with an issue generated while I'm trying deploy my PHP application using Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

I have my .config in .ebextensions which is as per below

```
commands:
    01-composer-selfupdate:
        command: "export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && composer.phar self-update -n"
    02-composer-install:
        command: "composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist --no-interaction"
option_settings:
    -   option_name: DB_SERVER
        value: '<server details>'
    -   option_name: DB_USER
        value: '<username>'
    -   option_name: DB_PASSWORD
        value: '<password>'
    -   option_name: DB_NAME
        value: '<db name>'
    -   namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
        value: /root
```

here is the code structure where composer is placed in root folder.
[image]

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd be your commands run in `~` and your application isn't stored there. Try `cd /path/to/your/site/code/folder && composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist --no-interaction"`.

Comment: I doubted, but when we do a deployment using beanstalk, will the path be always /var/www/html ? Any thoughts on how I can find the path of deployment if it is different from /var/www/html

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the help. I have tweaked the commands and it is working perfectly now.

Comment: Then you should answer your own question, that others may think it is useful.

Comment: @BMW I have updated that as part of solution. Do let me know if it is not showing up. The directory was updated to /var/app/ondeck as Amazon will not deploy directly into /var/www/html. As part of pre-deployment and post deployment, code will be moved to /var/www/current and /var/www/ondeck (as per the information I collected over multiple threads)

Comment: you did the update in your question, not submit a new answer.

Comment: @BMW Thanks mate. I have updated it now :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Picked up from logs to find the right folder:

```
+ EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
  + mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
  + mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
  + nohup rm -rf /var/app/current.old
```